# Javers in microservice architecture

Tags: spring-data-jpa, architecture, microservices, javers

When using JaVers, JaVers is creating four tables to function. I am looking for a way to use this library in a microservice environment. Our main goals are to audit action using ENUM, and track the modification with javers. I'm not sure how to use javers to handle audit from other micro service. I read from one answer that javers need to know the concrete class to handle serialisation, so my question is, is it possible to achieve such behavior using javers. By that I mean have an order, customer and audit micro service and query history from both customer and order in audit service.I was planning to use uuid to link action and changes, and maybe use it as the author.

I have implemented the library inside of one service and was starting to think of some way to outsource javers to another service to get history of multiple service. We use spring boot 2.6.7 with spring data and a postgreSQL database.